# Superconductors on each side of a flexible membrane what happens?

Tags: superconductivity

I have a sheet of flexible Kevlar 16th of an inch thick coated on each side with a high temperature superconductor, what happens when you put hundred amp of current into each side, and then 1000 and so on. And I'm assuming that the superconductor is bonded very well to the Kevlar, and that it is at a temperature cohesive to it superconducting. Will the 2 sides repel each other? Turning the Kevlar into a rigid structure? How rigid? Please put in the layman's terms!

Comment: Electromagnetic problems have to be well defined, and the one you pose is not. example: how/where will you apply a current of such dimensions to a surface ?

Comment: @annav, this problem is well-defined, and obviously the current is applied by just making a wire connection to the surface (probably using some silver epoxy).  And I think the answer to this problem has nothing to do with the metals being superconducting.

Comment: @ChrisGerig well I do not see your answer yet. If one has a sheet  and passes a current through the surface , the direction of the current will depend on where the "soldering" is applied . Whether there will be attraction or repulsion will depend on the relative currents' direction. Of course soldering superconducting surfaces is an extra problem: did you not read about the mishaps of the LHC superconductors due to soldering problems two years ago? Here is a compilation of some similar problems http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter8/8.6.html

Comment: I would want  the current to be applied in such a way  As to cause a mutual repulsion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we ignore that coating a Kevlar sheet with a high temperature superconductor is with current technology impossible one thing will happen:

It will rip the superconductor apart.

The Lorentz for such a high current at small distances is enormous. Here is a demonstration what happens: [5000 Amps through a copper bar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kapi6ZDvoRs&feature=related).